# Finiteness of the penalty of the thin-plate spline

Tags: machine-learning, smoothing

The original problem:
$$\min_{f}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\{y_i-f(x_i)\}^2 + \lambda J(f)$$
I write again the penalty of a thin-plate spline on $\mathrm{R}^2$:
$$J(f) = \int\int_{\mathrm{R^2}}\left[f_{x_1 x_1}''(x)^2 + 2f_{x_1 x_2}''(x)^2 + f_{x_2 x_2}''(x)^2\right]dx_1 dx_2$$
, and the form of solution:
$$f(x) = \beta_0 + \beta_1^T x + \sum_{j=1}^{N}\alpha_j h_j(x)$$
with $h_j$ are radial basis functions, $h_j(x)=||x-x_j||^2 \log||x - x_j||$.

I did read some documents talk about the thin-plate spline, they always attach the finite conditions of $J(f)$, that is: $\sum_j \alpha_j =0$ and $\sum_j \alpha_j x_j = 0$, but none of them show how derive these conditions. I spent about three hours to clarify them but not success :(.

Answer (score 2):

After spending a lot of time, I finally found the solution of the problem. It's really simple than my imagine. On basically, it's a extension of linear constraints of the natural cubic spline and for any cubic splines $g$ then $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(x)''dx$ is infinite unless $g$ is a natural cubic spline.

Now, we fix $x_2$ and then using the natural cubic spline on $x_1$ we obtain the coefficient vector $\theta_1$. Because the solutions of natural cubic spline and the thin-plate spline are both unique. Thus, we can present $\alpha = A\theta_1$ with $A$ is a non-singular matrix. Applying linear constraints of the natural cubic spline on $\theta_1$ we can derive linear constraints of the thin-plate spline on $x_1$. Doing the same thing for $x_2$ we can derive the overall conditions of the thin-plate spline.